# Do Docker Containers allow for changing of resources [CPU, Memory, Storage] while running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have several database processes running in docker containers. Under certain conditions, I'd like to throttle the Memory and Storage used by the container. I understand that docker-compose lets you restrict resource use, but I want to keep the container running if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you can look into docker [update command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/), you can update memory and CPU but storage is not listed in the docker-update command you can look further [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/872051/in-docker-17-how-is-disk-space-allocated-for-containers?rq=1) for storage option.

Update a container with cpu-shares and memory

To update multiple resource configurations for multiple containers:

```
$ docker update --cpu-shares 512 -m 300M abebf7571666
```

**Extended description**

> The docker update command dynamically updates container configuration.
>   You can use this command to prevent containers from consuming too many
>   resources from their Docker host. With a single command, you can place
>   limits on a single container or on many. To specify more than one
>   container, provide a space-separated list of container names or IDs.

**Warning:** 
The docker update and docker container update commands are not supported for Windows containers.

[docker-update-command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/)

Comment: This is really good. For storage the main reason I want to restrict storage is to prevent the service from successfully writing additional files. Is there some other way to disallow writes from that container - possibly from the host OS?